# Error messages when connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble connection to the database

Here is the code I am using

```
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database_name', $con);
```

And here is the results I get

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at     'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in /home/heartbeat_db/heartbeatsmart.com/php/config/dbconnect.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/heartbeat_db/heartbeatsmart.com/php/config/dbconnect.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111 in /home/heartbeat_db/heartbeatsmart.com/php/config/dbconnect.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/heartbeat_db/heartbeatsmart.com/php/config/dbconnect.php on line 3

Comment: your code is deprecated.

Comment: dont use mysql_connect
use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
or http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I was getting ready to switch, and I have an even better reason now. The new host only accepts mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use PDO or Mysqli. I prefer PDO because it also supports other databases than mysql so you can easier migrate if necessary.

You can easily make a connection through

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

If you want to use mysqli use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Answer (score 3):

try using this code

$con=mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
mysql_selectdb("database_name",$con);

Comment: How is that different from the sample source provided.

Comment: @Mathieu Is not their a difference between mysql_selectdb and mysql_select_db?

Comment: So how does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

mysqli_close($link);
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .      $mysqli->connect_error;
 }
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .      $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
if (!$con) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db = mysql_select_db('database_name', $con);
if (!$db) {
    die ('Can\'t use database_name : ' . mysql_error());
}
```